# Android: Start App automatically, tap on a button, switch to another App

Tags: android

is it possible to open an App on an Android device automatically (for example every hour) tap on a button (or screen coordinate) in this appp and then switch to another app?

Thanks for help!

Comment: your question has to be split into 2 different questions, as it contains 2 questions in fact.

Comment: If you are building some kind of reminder functionality, you might consider using [notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) instead of starting new activity.

Answer (score 2):

There is AlarmManager class that allows you to schedule Intent to be fired at specific time. Then you could start some other app with new Intent.

That said it is not advised to go in user way and randomly starting apps while he is doing something.